# Code Golf: MSM Random Number Generator

Tags: language-agnostic, random, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The challenge:

The shortest code by character count that will generate a series of (pseudo)random numbers using the **[Middle-Square Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method)**.

The **Middle-Square Method** of (pseudo)random number generation was first suggested by John Von Neumann in 1946 and is defined as follows:

**R<sub>n+1</sub> = mid((R<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup>, m)**

For example:

> 3456<sup>2</sup> = 11943936
>
> mid(11943936) = 9439
>
> 9439<sup>2</sup> = 89094721
>
> mid(89094721) = 0947
>
> 947<sup>2</sup> = 896809
>
> mid(896809) = 9680
>
> 9680<sup>2</sup> = 93702400
>
> mid(93702400) = 7024

Another example:

> 843<sup>2</sup> = 710649
>
> mid(710649) = 106
>
> 106<sup>2</sup> = 11236
>
> mid(11236) = 123
>
> 123<sup>2</sup> = 15129
>
> mid(15129) = 512
>
> 512<sup>2</sup> = 262144
>
> mid(262144) = 621
>
> 621<sup>2</sup> = 385641
>
> mid(385641) = 856
>
> 856<sup>2</sup> = 732736
>
> mid(732736) = 327
>
> 327<sup>2</sup> = 106929
>
> mid(106929) = 069
>
> 69<sup>2</sup> = 4761
>
> mid(4761) = 476
>
> 476<sup>2</sup> = 226576
>
> mid(226576) = 265

### Definition of `mid`:

Apparently there is some confusion regarding the exact definition of `mid`. For the purposes of this challenge, assume that you are extracting **the same number of digits as the starting seed**. Meaning, if the **starting seed had 4 digits**, you would **extract 4 digits** from the middle. If the  **starting seed had 3 digits**, you would **extract 3 digits** from the middle.

Regarding the extraction of numbers when you can't find the exact middle, consider the number **710649**. If you want to extract the middle 3, there is some ambiguity (**106** or **064**). In that case, extract the 3 that is closest to the beginning of the string. So in this case, you would extract **106**.

An easy way to think of it is to pad zeroes to the number if it's not the right number of digits. For example, if you pad leading-zeroes to **710649** you get **0710649** and the middle 3 digits now become **106**.

### Test cases:

**Make no assumptions regarding the length of the seed. For example, you cannot assume that the seed will always be 4-digit number**

A starting seed of **3456** that generates 4-digit random-numbers should generate the following series (first 10):

> 9439, 947, 9680, 7024, 3365, 3232, 4458, 8737, 3351, 2292

A starting seed of **8653** that generates 4-digit random numbers should generate the following series (first 10):

> 8744, 4575, 9306, 6016, 1922, 6940, 1636, 6764, 7516, 4902

A starting seed of **843** that generates 3-digit random numbers should generate the following series (first 10):

> 106, 123, 512, 621, 856, 327, 69, 476, 265, 22

A starting seed of **45678** that generates 5-digit ranom numbers should generate the following series (first 10):

> 86479, 78617, 80632, 1519, 30736, 47016, 10504, 3340, 11556, 35411

As far as leading zeroes are concerned, the answer is no leading zeroes should be displayed :).

Comment: Perl masters, this way \/ \/ \/ \/

Comment: Please make sure that your code works with the 947 test case as well!!!

Comment: Clarify how exactly `mid()` is defined.  What is round to which direction is completely non-obvious.

Comment: Also, is it acceptable to give answer with leading 0 or not?

Comment: @M28 Until J/APL come in and does it in a third the count ;-)

Comment: @doublep I've given a better explanation of mid

Comment: Update doesn't compute.  It says "assume that you are extracting the same number of digits as the original seed", yet test case says to produce 476 for seed 69.

Comment: @doublep I reworked that. Original seed means "starting seed". Ugh. My bad. Didn't realize that this algorithm isn't so clear on the definition of `mid`.

Comment: @Vivin: So it is not to produce one number?  The programs should produce 10 numbers?

Comment: @doublep a series of numbers is fine (you can keep generating them forever if you want). It doesn't have to be exactly 10 numbers. Just as long as it generates a series using the algorithm.

Comment: @Vivin - please add the test case in your example (3456 produces 9439, 947, 9680, ...) - the 947 breaks some of the shorter code that assumes all the squares have at least 7 characters.

Comment: @DVK I've added the test case for 3456.

Comment: Please check your solution against *all* posted test-cases and annotate any deviations. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it funny that most code golf questions systematically start out with a basic definition and then edge cases come out and only then an extensive writeup of the requirements happen? My, it's just like in the real world!

Comment: @JRL so true. This is my second code golf question. The first one was better defined!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## dc 26/37 chars

**26** chars the function for a single number:

```
?dZsl2^dZ1+ll-2/Ar^/All^%p
```

**37** chars with a 10 cycles loop:

```
?dZsl[2^dZ1+ll-2/Ar^/All^%pdzB>L]dsLx
```

Explanation of the function:

```
?            Input n
dZ           calculate number of digits
sl           store in register l
2^           calculate n^2
dZ           calculate number of digits of square
1+ll-2/Ar^/  n/(10^((squaredigits+1-l)/2)) int division truncates last digits 
All^%        n%(10^l) modulus truncates first digits
p            print the number
```

Test:

```
dc msml.dc
45678
86479
78617
80632
1519
30736
47016
10504
3340
11556
35411
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know dc can be used in this way.

Answer (score 15):

### Google Docs - Spreadsheet: 42 chars

```
=MID(C2^2,LEN(C2^2)/2-LEN(C2)/2+1,LEN(C2))
```

**Usage:**

- Put the initial seed in cell `C2`, and drag the formula for all the sequence.

**Test Cases:**

- **[Shared Document: Live preview of all test cases](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AuUlYW3gFE96dGdqTUtTRHhZMTVtRThYV3k5dzFsWHc&hl=en)**.

**Screenshot:**

[Code Golf: MSM Random Number Generator http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6830/golfo.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6830/golfo.png)

**Limitations:**

- This formula preserves leading zeros, but they could be trimmed using another column and applying `INT()` on the results.

Comment: So, including the "Fill Down" operation, shouldn't this be "42 chars + 1 click-drag"?

Comment: @Jeff: I would consider the clicks and drags as `stdin`, standard input :) ... That's how the user tells the spreadsheet how long the sequence should be.

Comment: @Jeff:I would consider 10 copies of 42 bytes of code to be 420 bytes total, putting this in last place by a wide margin -- which (at the risk of sounding harsh) is exactly where it belongs; duplicating code 10 times to produce 10 values is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

## Python (86 chars)

```
r=input()
l=len(str(r))
while 1:
 x=str(r*r)
 y=(len(x)-l)/2
 r=int(x[y:y+l])
 print r
```

Produces infinite sequence on stdout.  Note that backtick trick won't work at least on older versions with `long` type because of the ending `L` in representation.  Python 3 `print` as function would add 1 more char for closing paren.

Comment: @doublep I've explained the definition of `mid`. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for asking for more explanation by the way. I apologize for the initial vagueness of the rules. I hope the current set of rules make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

## C# (<s>96</s> <s>81</s> <s>79</s> <s>85</s> 84 chars)

**Change log**

- Added Yuliy's suggestion for 81
- Removed extra brackets for 79.
- Incremented count because I did not initially count the necessary spaces (only chars).
- Replacing 1.0 by 1d as per Camerons suggestion.

---

**My Code:**

```
    int F(int s, int l)
    {
        var r = "" + 1d*s*s;

        return int.Parse(r.Substring((r.Length - l) / 2, l));
    }
```

---

**Usage Example:**

```
    int s = 8653;
    int l = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        s = F(s, l);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

---

**Results**

```
---8653---
8744
4575
9306
6016
1922
6940
1636
6764
7516
4902

---843---
106
123
512
621
856
327
69
476
265
22

---45678---
86479
78617
80632
1519
30736
47016
10504
3340
11556
35411
```

Comment: First line can be replaced with var r = "" + (1.*s*s); to save some characters.

Comment: @AboutDev: Counting `int F(int s, int l){var r=""+1.0*s*s;return int.Parse(r.Substring((r.Length-l)/2, l));}` seems to be 87 chars. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AboutDev: In addition, I think you should derive the length of the seed inside your code, as the length is really functionally dependent on the seed.

Comment: @Daniel - I'm only counting char but if I include the spaces it comes to 85 for me.

Comment: @AboutDev: True, I missed two spaces. However I think indispensable whitespace should be counted.

Comment: @AboutDev - If the whitespace is important, it should be counted. Also you can remove the 1.0* to save 4 characters.

Comment: @Daniel - I'll update my number momentarily. 

@Cameron - You can't remove the 1.0* because doing so will result in the type of s * s to be evaluated as int and thus cause overflow for large numbers of s.

Comment: r.Length can be replaced with s*s%10. This allows you to put (""+s*s).Substring etc in place without having to declare the variable, saving more characters.

Comment: @AboutDev - About 1.0: I see now. :P The rest still works though.

Comment: Save 1 char by replacing 1.0 with 1d

Comment: @Cameron - Huzza! 1d it is!! :-)

Comment: If you don't care to return an integer, and can do with a string, the count decreases to 77 char.



'string F(int s, int l){var r=""+1d*s*s;return r.Substring((r.Length-l)/2,l);}'

Answer (score 2):

## Perl (<s>102</s> <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 79 chars)

`$s=$_;$d=length$s;map{$s*=$s;print 0+($s=substr$s,($s=~y///c-$d)/2,$d),$/}0..9`

```
echo -n 3456 | perl -ne '$s=$_;$d=length$s;map{$s*=$s;print 0+($s=substr$s,($s=~y///c-$d)/2,$d),$/}0..9'
9439
947
9680
7024
3365
3232
4458
8737
3351
2292
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript: 91 characters

```
function a(s,n){m=(s+'').length;while(n--)c=''+s*s,s=1*c.substr((c.length-m)/2,m);return s}
```

**Usage:**

```
a(3456, 4);     // 4th seed of 3456:   Returns: 7024
a(8653, 2);     // 2nd seed of 8653:   Returns: 4575
a(843, 10);     // 10th seed of 843:   Returns: 22
a(45678, 6);    // 6th seed of 45678:  Returns: 47016
```

**Full Test Cases:**

```
var tests = [3456, 8653, 843, 45678];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
   console.log('-------------');
   console.log('| Seed: ' + tests[i]);
   console.log('-------------');

   for(var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      console.log('| ' +  a(tests[i], j));
   }

   console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
}
```

**Test Results:**

```
-------------         -------------
| Seed: 3456          | Seed: 8653
-------------         -------------
| 9439                | 8744
| 947                 | 4575
| 9680                | 9306
| 7024                | 6016
| 3365                | 1922
| 3232                | 6940
| 4458                | 1636
| 8737                | 6764
| 3351                | 7516
| 2292                | 4902
~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-------------         -------------
| Seed: 843           | Seed: 45678
-------------         -------------
| 106                 | 86479
| 123                 | 78617
| 512                 | 80632
| 621                 | 1519
| 856                 | 30736
| 327                 | 47016
| 69                  | 10504
| 476                 | 3340
| 265                 | 11556
| 22                  | 35411
~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy - 82 chars

```
s=args[0]as int;def r(){f=s*s;g=f as String;t=g.size()/2;g=g[t-2..t+1];s=g as int}
```

using first argument as seed and output made by 4 base10 digits like in your examples..

Comment: does there have to be a space between `;` and `def`? 82 chars

Comment: Does this handle 3456 seed? (I don't read Groovy so not sure, sorry)

Comment: its output for 3456: 9439, 947, 9680, 7024, 3365, 3232, 4458, 8737, 3351, 2292

Comment: gonna check if it's "new mid definition compliant" tomorrow!

Comment: @Jack sorry about the confusion. My bad :p The rules have stabilized so it should still be the same tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (97 <s>99</s> chars)

Can probably still be shortened. Produces an infinite sequence, or at least it encounters 0, in which case it crashes.

```
i(f:l)x=x:i l(f x)
m n=head.filter((==n).length).i(cycle[init,tail])
b r n=n:b r(read$m r$show$n*n)
```

Usage: `b <length of number> <number>`

```
*Main> b 5 45678
[45678,86479,78617,80632,1519,30736,47016,10504,3340,11556,35411...
```

**Explanation**

Rather than applying substring and using string length arithmetic, this program iterates between removing the last character (`init`), and removing the first character (`tail`) until the desired length is reached.

As `iterate` as well as most Haskell functions assume that the function used is constant. Since we have the function itself changing, we need to implement a special version of `iterate`.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 80 chars

(from commandline)

```
$n=pop;$l=length$n;map{$n*=$n;print 0+($n=substr$n,(length($n)-$l)/2,$l),$/}0..9
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <strike>85</strike> <strike>76</strike> 69 chars (generates and prints 10 numbers)

```
n=gets
l=n.size
10.times{n=n.to_i;x=(n*n).to_s;p n=x[(x.size-l)/2,l]}
```

Reads from standard input.

Output

```
> ruby rand.rb < 3456
9439
947
9680
7024
3365
3232
4458
8737
3351
2292

> ruby rand.rb < 8653
8744
4575
9306
6016
1922
6940
1636
6764
7516
4902

> ruby rand.rb < 843
106
123
512
621
856
327
69
476
265
22

> ruby rand.rb < 45678
86479
78617
80632
1519
30736
47016
10504
3340
11556
35411
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell

---

Note: An infinite list is produced containing MSM random numbers.

---

### Function, 81

```
l=length
m k n=take k$drop(div(l n-k)2)n
r n=iterate(read.m(l$show n).show.(^2))n
```

Example usage:

```
r 34562
```

Example output:

```
[34562,94531,36109,3859,48918,92970,...
```

---

### Program, 103

```
l=length
m k n=take k$drop(div(l n-k)2)n
r n=iterate(read.m(l$show n).show.(^2))n
main=readLn>>=print.r
```

---

Answer (score 0):

**Perl** - <strike>112  - now, 108</strike> - now 95 (thanks to Zaid's idea) - chars sans white space, excluding test driver loop (e.g. I only counted the code to generate 1 sequence) - the code in the body of foreach loop.

```
@s=(8653,843,45678,3456);
foreach $s (@s){
    for(0..9){$s*=$s;$l=length($s);$L||=($l+1)/2;$H=($l+$L+1)/2;
        $s=substr($s,-$H,$L)+0;
        print "$s,"
    }
    print "\n";
    $L=0; @S=(); # Reset for next loop
}
```

Output:

```
8744,4575,9306,6016,1922,6940,1636,6764,7516,4902,
106,123,512,621,856,327,69,476,265,22,
86479,78617,80632,1519,30736,47016,10504,3340,11556,35411,
9439,947,9680,7024,3365,3232,4458,8737,3351,2292,
```

Compressed code that was 112:

```
for(0..9){$s*=$s;$l=length($s);$L||=($l+1)/2;$H=($l+$L+1)/2;$s=substr($s,-$H,$L)+0;print "$s,"}
```

Comment: NOTE: the current code obeys all the rules and correctly handles both given test cases AND the example case

Comment: No problem. No need for the space after `print`

Answer (score 0):

### **Lua** (<strike>135</strike> <strike>128</strike> 114 chars)

```
function r(i)
l=string.len
b=i or b
s=i or s
p=s*s..""
e=(l(p)-l(b))/2
s=tonumber(p:sub(e+1,e+l(b)))
return s
end
```

Seeds with one argument and returns first MSM random integer; subsequent calls with no arguments return next MSM random integer. Call will another integer to re-seed.

Test:

```
> =r(3456)
9439
> =r()
947
> =r()
9680
> =r()
7024
> =r()
3365
> =r()
3232
> =r()
4458
> =r()
8737
> =r()
3351
> =r()
2292
> =r(8653)
8744
> =r()
4575
> =r()
9306
> =r()
6016
> =r()
1922
> =r()
6940
> =r()
1636
> =r()
6764
> =r()
7516
> =r()
4902
> =r(843)
106
> =r()
123
> =r()
512
> =r()
621
> =r()
856
> =r()
327
> =r()
69
> =r()
476
> =r()
265
> =r()
22
> =r(45678)
86479
> =r()
78617
> =r()
80632
> =r()
1519
> =r()
30736
> =r()
47016
> =r()
10504
> =r()
3340
> =r()
11556
> =r()
35411
>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (66 chars)

Assuming integer inputs:

```
def r s,l=s.to_s.size;x=(s*s).to_s;y=x.size;x[(y-l)/2,l].to_i;end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, <strike>100</strike> <strike>94</strike> <strike>92</strike> <strike>91</strike> <strike>90</strike> 88 chars

Seed provided through standard input. Newlines included for readability:

```
@n=($n=pop)=~/./g;
for(0..9){
    @s=$n**2=~/./g;
    $n=join$\,splice@s,(@s-@n)/2,@n;
    print$/,$n+0
}
```